# How to make a table expression in ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

How to create a query like this (an example from MS SQL)

```
SELECT a, b FROM (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)) AS MyTable(a, b)
```

in ClickHouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select * from values('a String, b int',('a', 1),('b',2)) as MyTable;
┌─a─┬─b─┐
│ a │ 1 │
│ b │ 2 │
└───┴───┘

select * from values(('a', 1),('b',2));
┌─c1─┬─c2─┐
│ a  │  1 │
│ b  │  2 │
└────┴────┘


SELECT  (arrayJoin([('a', 1), ('b', 2)]) AS x).1 AS a, x.2 AS b;
┌─a─┬─b─┐
│ a │ 1 │
│ b │ 2 │
└───┴───┘
```